# Can't access PHImageManger (swift 3 xcode)

Tags: ios

I can't seem to access PHImageManager in xcode. Is this a package I need to download or something along those lines? Or is this not accessible in the latest version of xcode?

```
let imgManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
```

This simply gives me an error "use of unresolved identifier: PHImageManager"

Comment: Remember to accept my answer if it helped you, so it can help others.

Comment: Sure, sorry I'm new to stackoverflow. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add this to the top of your class:

```
import Photos
```

Comment: Thanks Timmy, greatly appreciated!